# Work around lacking const-correctness of external library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, const-correctness

I am using an external C++ library that lacks const-correctness. Lets say I am working with objects of the following class:

```
// Library.h
namespace Library {

class Message {
 public:
    std::string getData() {
        return data_;
    }
 private:
    std::string data_;
};

}  // namespace Library
```

Note that `getData()` returns a copy, thus a call to the method does not change the `Message` object and it should be `const`. However, the vendor decided it's not.
On my side of the code, const-correctness is important and the `Message` is to be used in a function like so:

```
// MyApplication.cpp

template<class T>
void handleMessage(const T& msg) {
    std::string content = msg.getData();
    // interprete and process content ...
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? In other words, how to work around the `error: passing 'const Library::Message' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers` error *without* changing the signature of the `handleMessage` function?

Comment: You can use `const_cast` as a last resort.

Comment: Note that the stripping  a `const` via `const_cast` on your reference will invoke *undefined behavior* if two things hold: (1) the original concrete object was, in fact, `const`, and (2) the object is modified. It does *not* invoke undefined behavior if the *either* of those are *false* (like yours... for now). Either way, this puts a tremendous onus on the coder, as it is *very* easy to intentionally code something that is at-the-time seemingly "safe", only later to discover someone has added usage which is passing a `const` object; the compiler had no chance to catch it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use wrapper with mutable member variable like:

```
#include <string>

class Message {
 public:
    std::string getData() {
        return data_;
    }
    Message(std::string data): data_{data} { }
 private:
    std::string data_;
};

class MessageWrapper {
 public:
    MessageWrapper(Message message): message{message} {}
    std::string getData() const {
        return message.getData();
    }
 private:
    mutable Message message;
};

template<class T>
void handleMessage(const T& msg) {
    std::string content = msg.getData();

}

int main() {
    MessageWrapper mw{{"abc"}};
    handleMessage(mw);
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pE3oW5qg8bRP1IYK)

**Edit:**

To force const correctness you could save once retrieved data from the message e.g.:

```
#include <string>
#include <optional>

class Message {
 public:
    std::string getData() {
        return data_;
    }
    Message(std::string data): data_{data} { }
 private:
    std::string data_;
};

class MessageWrapper {
 public:
    MessageWrapper(Message message): message{message} {}
    std::string getData() const {
        return (data)?(*data):(*(data = message.getData()));
    }
 private:
    mutable Message message;
    mutable std::optional<std::string> data;
};

template<class T>
void handleMessage(const T& msg) {
    std::string content = msg.getData();

}

int main() {
    MessageWrapper mw{{"abc"}};
    handleMessage(mw);
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tQ2PT7U0BRMQerFv)

Comment: also an option, but `mutable` is constness cheating as well

Comment: This should be the canonical way of patching.

Comment: @tobi303 it's not as the `message` is mutable so it is changeable all the time you use variable `mw`.

Comment: i am not saying that there is anything wrong with it, but you are still calling a non-const method on something that appears to be const. If the library ever decides to really modify observable state in that method, client code may break, I dont think there is any way to avoid that completely

Comment: @tobi303 oh, yes in this sense you are right... it is not guaranteed to get data with the same value at each call if the library does not guarantees that...

Comment: the correct way to guarantee that would be to declare the method as `const` ;). Nevermind, you already got my upvote and imho your answer is nicer than mine

Comment: mutable is clearly the way forward with a macro.  not only does it protect yourself from getData() actually changing the object, but it also gives you a nice easy way to remove the mutable when / if the library is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You basically have two options. You could use a `const_cast`

```
template<class T>
void handleMessage(const T& msg) {
    std::string content = const_cast<T&>(msg).getData();
    // interprete and process content ...
}
```

this is fine as long as you know for sure that `getData` really does not modify any members. Or if you dont mind some overhead you can make a copy:

```
template<class T>
void handleMessage(const T& msg) {
    T copy = msg;
    std::string content = copy.getData();
    // interprete and process content ...
}
```

... or as a third option, if you want to hide the `const_cast` from the call site you can wrap it:

```
class MyMessage {
     Message msg;
public:
     std::string getData() const {
         return const_cast<Message>(msg).getData();
     }
};
```

Comment: The library's `getData()` already creates a copy, so the overhead of storing it into a string is minimal.

Comment: @jotrocken well its an additional copy on top of the copy that `getData()` makes

Comment: yes, but at least one of them will be optimized by the compiler I hope